# Question about android studio (Database sql)

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I just wanted to know is it possible to do a database with check boxes? I'm trying to do a battleship game on android and was thinking to edit the database, that would change database value like 1 to 0 or the other way around (I'm going to do a login that player connects to the game window, then his can review the the check boxes and change the layout if he wants, and the sql will make him an 8x8 grid to play on). Maybe anyone have a better idea how to 8x8 database (i thought to limit the id number to 8 and just create 8 columns like x1, x2, x3.....)

Comment: what do you mean by _database_ here?  Is your question closer to "How store and retrieve array of int[8][8] in the DB?"

Comment: pretty much yea, i want to store and reatreave info from database by using check boxes , if in example there is 8 rows and 8 collums and i want to check a box in lets say (id number is a row and x is the collums) and i want to recieve data from 2 row; 5x collum by using checkboxes if the box is check then in the database it that specific spot it should be 1